# MongoDB CRUD operations in Ansible playbook

Tags: mongodb, ansible, mongodb-query, pymongo

Can anyone share a simple example of how to create database, a collection and perform CRUD operations in Ansible playbook using mongodb module.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ansible provides only common admin task like adding Shards to cluster or create users.

In this case you have to use the `shell` module, e.g.

```
- copy:
    # create or copy .js file with required commands
    dest: ~/script-file.js

- shell:
    cmd: mongo -u <user> -p <password> ~/script-file.js
```

For single command you can also use

```
- shell:
    cmd: mongo -u <user> -p <password>
    stdin: db.createCollection("col")
```